# Laravel 5 get data from multiple(3) tables

Tags: laravel-5

I have 3 tables: employees, employeeprofiles, employeeskills. The model relationship is as follows

```
1. Employee Model

    public function employeeprofile(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Employeeprofile', 'employee_id');
    }

    public function employeeskill(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Employeeskill', 'employee_id);
    }

2. Employeeprofile Model

    public function employee(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee', 'employee_id');
    }

3. Employeeskill Model

    public function employee(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee', 'employee_id');
    }
```

Employee table has columns id, fName, lName, email. Employee profile table has id, employee_id which is foreign key referencing employee table, join_date and others. Employeeskills table has columns id, employee_id which is foreign key referencing employee table and skill_name. One employee can have many skills. Now I want to access all the employees in the employee table with their profiles(employeeprofile table) and their skills(employeeskills table) in a controller and pass the variable to a view and display each employee using foreach. When I use two table (employee and employeeprofile), it works fine but on introducing the third table, I dont get results.

I need something like

```
$employees = Employee::with('employeeprofile')->employee()->get();
```

then I pass $employee varible to a view and perform

```
@foreach($employee as $employee)
Name: $employee->fName,
Joined: $employee->join_date,
Skill 1 : I list all the skills the employee has
@endforeach
```

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the advantages the Eloquent ORM gives you.

The methods (e.g. `employeeskill`) you've defined in your Employee model can be used to get all related objects when used as property/attribute.

```
$employees = Employee::all(); //get all (not soft-deleted) employees
foreach($employees as $e)
{
    $name = $e->fName; //The name of the employee
    $join = $e->join_date; //The join date
        foreach($employees->employeeskill as $skill) //Iterate over all skills of an employee
        {
            echo $skill->name; //echo the name of each skill
        }
}
```

Check out [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships) for more.